# Kalman filter problem with the output

Tags: control, kalman-filter, python, orientation

i want to use kalman filter to estimate my phone position, the measurments data is at this point just the accelerometer and the sampling rate is 3ms, i used the library pykalman, i have also wrote my own implementation of kalman filters and they both return the same results.
**transition matrix :**

```
dt = 0.003
F = np.matrix([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0,dt,0.0,0.0,0.5*(dt)*(dt), 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,dt,0.0,0.0, 0.5*(dt)*(dt), 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,0.0,dt,0.0, 0.0, 0.5*(dt)*(dt)],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,dt, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0, dt, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0, 0.0, dt],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
```

**measurment matrix**

```
H =np.matrix([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
```

**measurment noise**

```
rp = 0.02  # Noise of Position Measurement
R = np.matrix([[rp, 0.0, 0.0],
               [0.0, rp, 0.0],
               [0.0, 0.0, rp]])
```

**initial state vector**

```
X0 = np.matrix([0,0,0,0,0,0,measurments[0][0],measurments[0][1],measurments[0][2]])
```

**state covariance matrix**

```
P0 =np.matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0],
    [0, 1, 0,0, 0, 0,0,0,0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,0,0,0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,0,0,0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0,0,0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1,0,0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,1,0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,1]])
```

i load the accelerometer data, and then use pykalman to find x,y and z.

```
measurments = []
for i in range(len(df_acc)):
    measurments.append([df_acc.iloc[i]['x'],df_acc.iloc[i]['y'],df_acc.iloc[i]['z']-9.82])
n_timesteps = len(measurments)
n_dim_state = 9
filtered_state_means = np.zeros((n_timesteps, n_dim_state))
filtered_state_covariances = np.zeros((n_timesteps, n_dim_state, n_dim_state))

kf = KalmanFilter(transition_matrices = F, 
                  observation_matrices = H, 
                  observation_covariance = R, 
                  initial_state_mean = X0, 
                  initial_state_covariance = P0)

for t in range(n_timesteps):
    if t == 0:
        filtered_state_means[t] = X0
        filtered_state_covariances[t] = P0
    else:
        filtered_state_means[t], filtered_state_covariances[t] = (
        kf.filter_update(
            filtered_state_means[t-1],
            filtered_state_covariances[t-1],
            measurments[t]))
```

the results are shown in the picture, the data i captured with my phone while walking in a small appartment i can't have walked 1 mile lol, plus i've been walking in a straight line the other axis claim that ive walked 200 meters along x and z which is impossible. I can'
t find where i made a mistake.

[image]

Comment: You've asked for where you've gone wrong in a moderately complex system that's not reproducible. Please edit your question to isolate more closely what your problem is. You may find that if you reduce the scope then you'll find your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't made a mistake. There is a bias in your accelerometer readings (which is a true statement for *all* accelerometers) and then you're numerically integrating that bias, which results in position drift.

Comment: It can also be noted that just using accelerations yields an unobservable model, for which any type of observer/estimator/filter can not guarantee stability/convergence.